# Colorful stains on a movie, Droid 3

Tags: android, movie

I have been creating an app on Droid 3 that records movies, unfortunatey I have a problem with that. When I play a movie recorded on my Droid with my app, there are colorful stains on the film: [colorful stains on the film http://img41.imageshack.us/img41/4011/screenrwx.jpg](http://img41.imageshack.us/img41/4011/screenrwx.jpg)

However, normally those stains are mainly green, but after taking Print Screen it turned into orange. The problem is strange for me, because my app records movies with no problem on my two other phones (Samsung and Motorola). What's more, I have noticed that bunch of app from Android Market, which are movie recorders, have the same problem as my application. However, there exists application called DailyRoads Voyager, that works with no problems on my Droid 3, and native camera also works. So the question is - why do those colorful stains show up?

If you need more info, this is a link to download an *.apk file so you can check what is wrong with my app: http://www.speedyshare.com/vyEzB/Projekt.zip. Recorded movies are saved on sdcard, as "videooutput.mp4". Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Do DailyRoads Voyager etc record in mp4 format? It seems like codec problem

Comment: Yes, DailyRoads and mine app record in mp4 format. I also think it might be codec problem, however I used program called MediaInfo which shows what codecs are used in certain film. According to MediaInfo, all codecs are the same in both films from both applications (mine and DailyRoads). Actually the only things that differ those two films is bitrate. Do you think it may cause a problem?